# Setting Incremental Refresh for Every 30 Minutes

Tags: powerbi, refresh

[image: Incremental_Refresh]
I have a question about incremental refresh procedure. I have a table and I'm setting up incremental refresh on it. But I can only choose refresh rows as minimum 1 day. I want to set this specialty as for every 30 minutes. Is that possible? I couldn't find any answer to this question. I've only seen that I can set refresh for every 30 minutes in dataflows.

Is there anybody who will give me detailed information about this subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to my researches the incremental refresh for every 30 minutes can be set via dataflows.